# Modifying graphical elements with PL/SQL - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

I am currently trying to migrate Forms' Applications developped ten years ago to Oracle Apex. For some context, the database in which Forms applications are currently running is the Oracle EE **6i**, and will be soon upgraded to the **12.2g**, hence the need for migration. The data stored within the tables is to big to migrate (like 4To) so we need an alternative to Forms, but we cannot change the DB, and cannot keep Forms (which is let's be honest, outdated a little). I am currently on Oracle XE for my tests and on Apex  20.2.0.00.20 to start my migration (before upgrading).

The thing is, I have some issues with how Apex and Forms are working differently.

I am really blocking on the following issue since my migration:
In Forms, it was really easy to **change the color of a button** for exemple by calling a Forms method in a certain way depending on a condition (for exemple a SELECT return). Here, in Apex, I am trying to do the same.

I know that there are ten other ways of doing the same, with JS for exemple which I already succeedly do, but when I tried to create my second appplication I realised that compared to Forms, **Apex cannot reference/generalise parts of the code(or applications)** for different applications (and certainly not for different workspaces). So Javascript is a good solution but not as efficient as PL/SQL which is easier to generalise and will (in my opinion) use less exchange between the db and the client, since stored on the db.

That is why I decided to rely on **PL/SQL Stored Procedure** which will be specified in the database and called directly in each application where I need the process/computations.But I cannot find the same as in Forms, with my graphical methods helping me do what I need.

**I am open to alternative of PL/SQL package/procedure/function** if it can keep the same propreties (generalisation and minimum echange between client and db). These are important point since I have around 200 applications to migrate, starting with what we can call 'brick' which will compose the other simpler applications.
Btw: CSS is an option I studied, like HTML with PL/SQL dynamic content but I read that it was either not simple enough to integrate, or that it could be deprecated, so if it is the solution you are using, I could use a really detailled explaination or an exemple.

To give you an instance:

- I click on a button triggering a PL/SQL stored procedure
- Procedure checks some conditions in the db (like if a process is currently running)
- PL/SQL update a table, change a variable in procedure and returns '*green*'
- The button becomes *green*, a message is displayed ('You have permission to do this!')

*PS: if there are Apex Method modifying the graphical aspect, could I have a documentation ?*

Thank you a lot for helping me resolve this issue, I have been stuck for days...

*I tried Javascript bu the generalisation was too much a problem. I tried the HTML injecting but didn't work, I tried updating CSS but was not what I expected. I tried different PL/SQL method but couldn't find a way to connect PL/SQL with Apex/CSS/HTML...*

Comment: Use the tag "oracle-apex". The "apex" tag is used by a product by Salesforce that is unrelated to oracle APEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a bit of getting used to how APEX works, but everything can be done and once you get up to speed, you'll find there pretty simple ways to get things done. To achieve what you describe, this is what you'd do.

- Create a dynamic action on click of button
- Add the following actions to the dynamic actions

  - an action of type "execute pl/sql". This is your "Procedure checks ...". In this pl/sql code you can set page item values (make sure to reference those in "items to return" so the new values is set in the session. There is no reason to have 2 different pl/sql procedures, you can just put them in 1 block. This procedure would return the "green" - but more about this later.
  - an action to add a class to the button under certain conditions.

Note that the "green" is not something you should decide. In apex, there are a lot of [layout modifier classes](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/color-and-status-modifiers) pre-defined. In your case, it makes sense to use the "success" modifier (which happens to be green).

To check how you want the button to look, there is a tool called the "[button builder](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/button-builder)", you can use that to see what classes you should add/remove to change the look of the button.

Note that 20.2 is not a recent version. It was released in 2020. Since then 4 more releases have been made available: 21.1,21.2,22.1 and 22.2. It is advised to be on the latest version.

Here is a basic example. I have a page with a select list (P117_SELECTLIST), a hidden item to hold the button status (P117_BUTTON_STATE) and a button (MYBUTTON). The select list has 2 static values:

[image]

The dynamic action for serverside code is :
[image]

Note the items to submit and return values. P117_SELECTLIST is submitted so the pl/sql process picks that up from the client and  P117_BUTTON_STATE is returned to the client so it is available for any future use.

Then I have 4 classes to set the button style. One to add success class, one to remove success class, one to add warning class, one to remove warning class. Below is the first one. The only think different in those 4 actions in the class name and the client condition. It can probably done with javascript directly as well with only 1 action.

[image]

I'd strongly suggest to update the db version to a version that supports the latest version of apex. It will save you a lot of development worries. Most people of forums only have the latest version available.

Comment: If I understand correctly, In one dynamic action with two actions, the first one with PL/SQL code (fetching the data, in this case 'green' or 'u-color-5-bg') and the second action, defining the style by adding a class to the selected object. But then I have two questions, the first one is how you take into argument what the PL/SQL function returns for the second action ? and the second one, how do you check a condition in the current page with PL/SQL ? If you have an exemple, that would be helpful thank you. PS: I use the 20.2 because of the Oracle DB version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand better with your explaination. 
I know that we should update the DB version but since the DB needs to have Forms running while we migrate the applications to Apex, for now at least, we can't go up from the 12.1g of Oracle. I agree with you that the latest version of Apex is better.